# How do I select a specific id from a table, and at the same time find out how many rows there in total within just ONE query?

Tags: mysql

MySQL (table)

```
+----+--
| id |
+----+--
| 1  |
+----+--
| 2  |
+----+--


$a = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `id` = '1'");
```

I want to select **id 1**, however, I also want to see how many rows there are in total (in the case above it would be **2 rows**). Is that even possible to do within just ONE query?

Comment: not really, the only way i could do it was if i was using a limit, then there is a trick for that but this im not too sure

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, it doesn't matter then lol, but thanks for your help anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would do this using a subquery

```
SELECT T.*, (select count(*) FROM `table`) AS total FROM `table` T where id='1'
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Still technically 2 queries, but only 1 workload:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM table ORDER BY FIELD(id, 1) LIMIT 1;
SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

But SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS is not always faster! See http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/28/to-sql_calc_found_rows-or-not-to-sql_calc_found_rows/

Instead, I would bite the bullet, and at least take some solace knowing that at least you're doing it in a mysql_multi_query().

Answer (score 0):

Stored Procedure would mean 1 "query".

`CALL yourfunction();`

Answer (score 0):

The only way I see now is to use subquery with proper main query modifications. SQL queries usually return only one dataset, so you mus be creative with this. ;]